# multivariate limits; general method for finding limit...for functions of 2 variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{\sin(x)\sin(y)}{x^2+y^2}$ 
the limit is undefined.

I would like to know if the following method is sufficient to prove that the limit is undefined:

**step1:** $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(x,0)}\frac{\sin(x)\sin(0)}{x^2+0^2}=0$$

**step2:** $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,y)}\frac{\sin(0)\sin(y)}{0^2+y^2}=0$$

**step3:** but
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(x,x)}\frac{\sin(x)\sin(x)}{x^2+x^2}=\frac{\sin(x)^2}{2x^2}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\sin x}{x})^2$$

and as $x$ then $\rightarrow 0$  $\frac{\sin(x)^2}{2x^2}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\sin x}{x})^2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$

hence the limit does not exist.

1. Does this make sense?
2. Does this method (the '**3 steps**') always work for functions of two variables?
3. Would it be valid to use the same method to prove: $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2}=0$

Thank you!

Comment: All steps above look right.

Comment: I'm wondering though would the same method work for every 2-variable function; i.e. (1) sub. into limit (x,0) (2) sub. into limit (y,0) and (3) sub. into limit (x,x). If all 3 answers give consistent solutions then the limit exists; if there is at least one inconsistent answer then there is no limit. So my question is would i sometimes need to take another arbitrary step 4) i.e. sub into limit (x,2x); sub into limit (x,x^3) etc... and exhaust every possible step conceivable until there is an inconcistency...

Comment: If they are inconsistent then the limit doesn't exist, but if they are consistent then you haven't proven anything. In fact there are functions that have a consistent limit travelling on any *line*, but not along non-linear paths, meaning that the limit still doesn't exist. Wikipedia has a good discussion on this [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariable_calculus).

Comment: I see, thank you; wikipedia states: "Continuity in each argument does not imply multivariate continuity." This means, my argument may only be used to prove there is no limit. Is there any other method in which I may prove there is a limit, i.e. for my second example in "step 3."

Comment: I have my answer for the example I solved above; but for the other example below: lim(x,y)--> (0,0) for {x^3-y^3}/{x^2+y^2}=0; I have no idea how to prove mathematically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the third: In this kinds of limits, you can take $r_α (t)=(t,αt)$ and put it into your function to find path wise limit of $f$  when $t$  tends to $0$ . After simplifying the original function, if the limit of last expression approaches to zero then probably your original function has limit $0$  at $(0,0)$ . Now, you have to use $ϵ,δ$  to prove your limit. Note that we see $\lim_ {t→0} r_α (t)=(0,0)$ . There are some small magic points in these limits also. See what @Jennifer Dylan  here noted https://math.stackexchange.com/a/128564/8581. Read two comments below of it and take a great way for such these limits. I hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks! that makes sense :)