# What is the limit of $\frac {x^4 +y^4}{x^3 +y^3}$ as $(x,y) \to(0,0)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

What is the limit of $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \dfrac {x^4 +y^4}{x^3 +y^3}$$
if it exists?

I have tried to solve it by converting it to polar system  $(x,y)=(r\cos a,r\sin a)$ and another settings. However I could not find the limit and not to show that there is no limit.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, part of the problem is that $x^3+y^3$ can be zero in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$, so you have to be extra careful about your domain.

Comment: you have a problem along the line y= -x.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^4+y^4}{x^3+y^3}$ exist?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/128554/does-lim-x-y-to-0-0-fracx4y4x3y3-exist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit does not exist. You can derive multiple limiting values that depend on what path you choose to $(0,0)$. eg. if you choose to follow the path $y=kx$ then you get $(1+k^4)/(1+k^3)$.

Edit: Sorry, right idea, wrong execution (an x got lost somewhere).

Sami's got the same idea: if we head to the origin along $y = -x(1+kx^n)$ we get

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{(x^4 + x^4 (1 + kx^n)^4)}{(x^3 - x^3(1 + kx^n)^3)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{2x^4 + o(x^4)}{-3kx^{n+3} + o(x^{n+3})}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to 0} (-2x^{1-n}/3k)$$

which is $0$ for $n<1$, any positive value we choose for $n=1$, and diverges off to $\infty$ for n>1.

Comment: For $y=kx$ I get the limit $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x\frac{1+k^4}{1+k^3}$...

Comment: @Julia Hayward the idea of selecting lines is good: when is $\frac{1+k^4}{1+k^3}$ divergent? Take that $k$ to prove that the original limit...

Answer (score 3):

The idea to prove that the limit doesn't exist is to choose a direction such that $x^3+y^3$ is convergent to $0$ faster than $x^4+y^4$ so let $y=-x+x^3$ hence we find
$$x^3+y^3=x^3+(-x+x^3)^3=3x^5+o(x^5)\ \text{and}\ x^4+y^4=x^4+(-x+x^3)^4=2x^4+o(x^4)$$
hence
$$\lim_{(x,y=-x+x^3)\to(0,0)} \dfrac {x^4 +y^4}{x^3 +y^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac {2x^4 +o(x^4)}{3x^5 +o(x^5)}=\infty $$

Comment: That's a fine answer!